# jQuery Advanced Selector for Multiple Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to add `hidden` class on two elements.

```
$("#grid").closest(".ui-jqgrid").addClass("hidden");
$("#grid").closest(".ui-jqgrid").prev("h3").addClass("hidden");
```

For the following markup,

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <h3>Heading 1</h3>
    <div class="ui-jqgrid  hidden" id="" dir="rtl" style="width: 1035px;">
        <div class="jqgrid-overlay ui-overlay" id=""></div>
        <div class="loading row" id="" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div class="ui-jqgrid-view" role="grid" id="">
            <div class="ui-jqgrid-titlebar ui-jqgrid-caption-rtl" style="display: none;">
                <a role="link" class="ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close HeaderButton " title="" style="left: 0px;">
                    <span class="ui-jqgrid-headlink glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-up"></span></a>
                <span class="ui-jqgrid-title"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="ui-jqgrid-bdiv">
                <div style="position: relative;">
                    <div></div>
                    <table id="grid" class="ui-jqgrid-btable">
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can I do this in one line without finding the `closest(".ui-jqgrid")` twice? I don't want to add more classes to markup and also I don't want to use a JS variable here. Can anybody with strong selectors suggest a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Just chain the methods. jQuery **returns** the manipulated object every time you call a method, so you can just call the next method on the returned object.

This is known as [chaining](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp)

```
$("#grid").closest(".ui-jqgrid").addClass("hidden").prev("h3").addClass("hidden");
```

---

**Explanation**

```
$("#grid")  // returns #grid
.closest(".ui-jqgrid")  // returns .ui-jqgrid 
.addClass("hidden")  // returns .ui-jqgrid
.prev("h3")  // returns the previous h3 element of .ui-jqgrid
.addClass("hidden");  // returns the h3
```

---

**UPDATE (Chained and no need for new class)**

```
// Select the closest '.ui-jqgrid', find its parent and hide it's direct children ('h3' and '.ui-jqgrid' div)
$('#grid').closest('.ui-jqgrid').parent().children().addClass('hidden');
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way we can use addClass("hidden") only once?

Comment: Not in this way, addClass gets executed on differend elements each time

Comment: Thanks for the updated ansers, actually as I mentioned above, I don't want to add more classes to markup.

Comment: What about this one. Any effects on performance?

$("#grid").closest(".ui-jqgrid").parent().find(".ui-jqgrid, h3, h4").addClass("hidden");

Comment: why h4? I plan to use it for all headings eventually.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
$("#grid").closest('.col-sm-12').find(".ui-jqgrid, h3").addClass("hidden");
```

As you have the id of the grid `#grid` the traverse up at the wrapper element of all then use `.find()` method ***which can take multiple comma separated selectors*** then add the class on the found elements.

As per your comment you can change to this:

```
$("#grid").closest('[class^="col-sm"]')
```

Comment: Yes! It does have performance boost as `.find()` is better than `.prev()` and it uses the addclass method just once. So, surely this is better.

Comment: I am trying this one

$("#grid").closest(".ui-jqgrid").parent().find(".ui-jqgrid, h3, h4").addClass("hidden");

Comment: This is also fine but you are traversing two times up one with closest and again with parent which seems to be odd to me. Although it would work.

Comment: That's because the "ui-jqgrid, h3, h4" elements are the siblings of "ui-jqgrid" and I have to do add the same class to all of them. Any better alternatives?

Comment: The problem is, "col-sm-12" is not the same in all my grids, and I am looking for a selector which works everywhere.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you are putting, and I am very thankful. But I really don't want to traverse there, because there are multiple grids under that ('[class^="col-sm"]').